# Avoid re render with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have some value that comes from Redux through props and I want to NOT render the component again when this value changes.

I found some answers saying that I can use Memo but I don't know if this is the best option for my case?

My "code":

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    return ...;
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  myVar: state.myVar
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

`myVar` changing shouldn't re render the component in this case.

Comment: Please share your code. We can't give you any answer if we don't know what you are doing

Comment: @Vencovsky added code

Answer (score 5):

React.memo can do the job, you can pass a custom equality check function to perform a rerender only when it returns a falsy value. I never faced a case where you want to completely ignore a value update from your Redux store, maybe it shouldn't be stored there ?

**Memo API**

eg: `React.memo(Component, [areEqual(prevProps, nextProps)])`

**UseSelector API**

Another way would be to use `useSelector` with a custom equality check function:

[useSelector Redux API Reference](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector)

**Connect API**

If you still want to stick with mapStateToProps, you can also pass a custom equality check function as a parameter of the connect function:

[areStatePropsEqual Redux API Reference](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#arestatepropsequal-next-object-prev-object-boolean)

**Edit: useRef solution**

By using useRef, you store a mutable variable that will be kept as it is for the whole lifetime of the component.

**Example based on yours:**

```
const StoreMyVar = (WrappedComponent) => ({myVar, ...props}) => {
  const myRefVar = useRef(myVar)
  return <WrappedComponent myVar={myRefVar} {...props} />
}

const MyComponentWithImmutableVar = StoreMyVar(MyComponent)
```

Comment: it's a swiper component, the store saves the swiped ones, but if I re render using the swiped ones as reference it glitches out, however, other state change in the component doesn't break it, I'll try memo and see if it works, thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, cause with that you compare previous props to next props, but I don't want to compare them, I just want to ignore the change of a single prop but acknowledge the other ones

Comment: I think in your case I would delete the prop I want to ignore in both the prevProps and nextProps objects before returning a shallow comparison of the two resulting objects. (resuming to the default behaviour)

Comment: I added another solution using the useRef hook in my post !

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), but you can use it just with functional components. Be careful, it is not tested.

```
const MyComponent(props) {
  return ...;
}

const areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.myVar === nextProps.myvar
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   myVar: state.myVar
});

export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```